# Comparing string and number in Python

Tags: python, string, numbers

What would happen if you compare strings with a number? What's happening behind the scenes? Why doesn't this give me an error and instead print "meh" all the time regardless whether the b is within a and c or not?

```
a = "900"
b = 1055
c = "2000"

if a <=b <= c:
    print "bingo"
else:
    print "meh"
```

Comment: That question has been answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3270689/2207688

Answer (score 0):

I believe if you compare the strings with the regular numbers, it will instead grab the ASCII values of the characters in the string and compare them via that value. So `b` would not be less than `c`, as the ASCII values for the characters in "2000" would be significantly lower than the integer value `1055`.

Also, a nicer answer can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3270680/how-does-python-compare-string-and-int) for the same question.

Comment: thank you so much for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

in fact, a will be greater than c than b because, python will use the first character as the value in ascii

```
>>> a > b # ord('9') is 57 which is greater than ord('1') 49
True
>>> a > c # ord('2') is 50, so a is greater because the first '9' value is greater that '2' (57 > 50)
True
>>> c > b # same thing, ord('2') is 50 and ord('1') is 49, so c is greater
True
```